# Tags tooltip not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

The tag tooltip seems to be broken:

[image]

I can see a response coming back from `https://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=css&newstyle=true&_=1599051203130` but the front end seems to not be rendering it correctly.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [Tag suggestions are cropped by the tag bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353785/289905) on MSE.

Comment: Thanks for the report; you are right - the error was entirely mine. It is now resolved. Sorry about that.